# Topology to define continuous functions to the discrete plane

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics

If you have a function from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, you can define a continuous function as a function for which the preimage of every open subset in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

In the discrete case, you can define functions that "look continuous" from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ as functions so that for every step of 1, the image point is adjacent to the original point.

Is it possible to consider topologies on $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ so that the definition of the continuity "preimage of open is open" in the first paragraph leads to exactly the sets of "continuous" functions defined in the second paragraph ?

Comment: A function whose image is just $\{0,1\}$ is always continuous in this sense, but can have $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ be any set at all.

Comment: @aschepler you would need to show $\{1\}$ is open, too

Comment: @ZoeAllen Good point. More exactly, if some open set $U$ is neither $\emptyset$ nor $\mathbb{N}$, then there exists some $a$ such that exactly one of $a$ and $a+1$ is in $U$, and we instead consider a function with image $\{a,a+1\}$. Otherwise, the topology is the trivial topology, which doesn't help describe this sense of "continuous".

Comment: @aschepler Hrmm again that's neater than my answer. I think it deserves to be written up as another anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a topology $T$ on $\mathbb{N}$ so that continuity $(\mathbb{N},T) \to (\mathbb{N},T)$ works like that.

Consider a function $f$ with a jump of more than $1$, i.e. $|f(m+1)-f(m)|>1$. To stop functions like this from being continuous at $m$, it must that there is an open neighbourhood of $f(m)$ which does not contain $f(m+1)$. And this must hold for any possible $f(m+1)$ with a jump of more than 1$.

As such, $f(m)$ has an open neighbourhood in $T$ not containing any number more than $1$ away from it. So $f(m)$ has a finite open neighbourhood with no more than $3$ elements.

Also, $g: m \mapsto m+1$ is continuous, so any shift of an open set by $1$ must also be an open set. This also works for subtracting $1$. But then we can shift the open neighbourhood of $f(m)$ up so that its lowest element is now where its highest element was. But then the intersection of these open sets will be a singleton. And we can shift that singleton by any amount to show every other singleton is open. So the topology must be discrete.

But obviously the discrete topology doesn't satisfy your criteria either.

---

Alternative ending based on @aschepler's comment:

Every $n$ having a finite neighbourhood means there are neighbourhoods with a non-zero minimal element. This can be shifted to make an open set containing $1$ but not $0$. You can then take a function with image $\{0,1\}$ and $f^{-1}[1]$ must be open. But this preimage can be any set, so every set is open.